# Button linking to a new page, doesn't work

Tags: android, hyperlink, rss

I am creating a program that is supposed to show an RSS Feed once a button is clicked.

I have a main class, a Screen 1, and Screen 2 
and a main xml file and screen 1 and screen 2 in the layout.

Now I tried before with the main xml and class being the RSS Feed and it worked fine

However, now when I try to make Screen1 (screen1) the place where the feed is displayed, I just get a black screen.

I am wondering why this is happening, as I told by Screen1 class to link to the screen1 xml file.

Main Class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;


public class SImpleRssReader2Activity extends Activity {





@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button videoNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videoButton) ; 
        videoNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              setContentView(R.layout.screen2);



                //  Intent i = new Intent();
               // i.setClassName("rahul.application.WunApp", "rahul.application.WunApp.screen1");
               // startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button newsNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newsButton);
        newsNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

                //  Intent i = new Intent();
               // i.setClassName("rahul.application.WunApp", "rahul.application.WunApp.screen1");
               // startActivity(i);
            }
        });




}
}
```

Screen 1:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;


    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class Screen1 extends ListActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       List<String> headlines;
       List<String> links;





    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) links.get(position));
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
       startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
         // Initializing instance variables
            headlines = new ArrayList<String>();
            links = new ArrayList<String>();



            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss");

                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                    // We will get the XML from an input stream
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

                    /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
                     * However, we should take in consideration that the rss feed name also is enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
                     * As we know, every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title>...."
                     * so we should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
                     * and take in consideration only "<title>" tag which is a child of "<item>"
                     *
                     * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable.
                     */
                boolean insideItem = false;

                    // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            insideItem = true;
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            if (insideItem)
                                headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                            if (insideItem)
                                links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                        }
                    }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        insideItem=false;
                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Binding data
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

            setListAdapter(adapter);



        }
    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
           try {
               return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               return null;
             }
        }
```

Main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/welcome" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >






        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newsButton"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/button1" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >





        <Button
            android:id="@+id/videoButton"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/button3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

screen1 xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



<ListView
android:id="@+android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So to summarize: It worked when I just had the main class and xml, but now that I am linking to a new class and xml, it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

point 1 - You should not do Network related work in UI thread Use Asynctask or thread with handler

Point 2- You have various views in main.xml but in screen1 xml only list view that  may possible you may not have data foe list in screen1

point 3- use "@android:id/list" as ID for ListActivity

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: My data for list in screen1 should be the RSS feed supplied in Screen1.java ... But I was able to get the RSS feed without using an Asynctask (don't want to try with it right now because haven't learned how to do it with Asynctask) on my main.xml, all I need is to be able to display in screen1.xml with a link from main.xml ... I know there probable is a more efficient way, but for me this seems like the easiest to understand. Also point 3 didn't really do anything. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have anything to do with these being commented out in your code

```
  //Intent i = new Intent();
           // i.setClassName("rahul.application.WunApp",      "rahul.application.WunApp.screen1");
           // startActivity(i);
```

Did you make sure that in your manifest you put inside the application  block

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity android:name=".SImpleRssReader2Activity" /> // your class names
<activity android:name=".screen1" />
<activity android:name=".screen2" />
```

you usually need these when using intents.

sidebar:
really funny that your working on the same exact thing Iam doing. I needed an rss feed for something and tried that same piece of code. Didn't work for me at all don't know how you got it to work at all but nice. I used a different piece of code for mine. Not really used to such a high level language like java myself I think C is an easier language once you get going.